# mathtools: the use of intertext in align

Tags: page-breaking, align

If I use `\intertext{some sentence or two}` and then continue `align`, will the `align` environment break across a page break where the text is inserted or is it still unbreakable?

> If it is still unbreakable, is there a way to make it breakable without using a new `align` environment and `\phantom{some equation}` to re-align the the alignment position.

So consider:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
Suppose this text takes us just above the page breaking point (let's say 5 lines).
\begin{align*}
1 &= 1\\
2 &= 2\\
\intertext{sentence 1\\
sentence 2.}
3 &= 3\\
4 &= 4\\
5 &= 5
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

If the box doesn't break, there will be a significant gap of white space which will look ugly.  However, if it breaks at `\intertext{}`, the look will flow more natural picking up the remainder of the `align` environment after the page break.

Comment: Line breaks/paragraph breaks in `\intertext` doesn't work, by the way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, a quick test shows that it can break before the `\intertext`. If that is insufficient, you can add `\allowdisplaybreaks` to allow page breaks between lines in multi-line math environments.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
% \allowdisplaybreaks
\begin{document}
\vspace*{8cm}
Suppose this text takes us just above the page breaking point (let's say 5 lines).
\begin{align*}
1 &= 1\\
2 &= 2\\
\intertext{sentence 1 sentence 1sentence 1 sentence 1 sentence 1.
sentence 2.}
3 &= 3\\
4 &= 4\\
5 &= 5
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about `allowdisplaybreaks`.

Comment: @dustin: See section **3.9 Vertical spacing and page breaks in multiline displays** (p 8) in the [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsldoc.pdf).